# How can I combine two separate object?

Tags: modeling, texturing

[image: Image About This]

I seperated the one cylinder to two parts for texturing

(The reason why is it separated, ı don't have idea "how can ı different texturing on the one part?")

Now,I want combine the different two parts like in the beginning(like one cylinder)

Thank you for helps :)

Answer (score 2):

First, select both objects, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. Then, go into *Edit Mode*, select the both rings of vertices on the ends of the gap, press <kbd>W</kbd> and then select *Bridge Edge Loops*.

In order to have different texturing for different parts, you'll need to make the different textures into different materials, (so if you want two textures, you'll make two textures,) and then, select vertices you want the material to be put on, select the material you want to put on them, and press the *Assign* button, which is under the material name.

Read: [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh) (frequently asked question)

Answer (score 1):

You can combine two objects by selecting both of them and using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to 'join' the geometry into one single object.